# ExtJS grid contents checking

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS 4... I use grid (not to big) 30 x 20. In time of program session I have to check if any data were entered to the grid (even one cell) and then write data to the dick or not.

How to check if any cell of grid was changed?
I can check all data in loops obviously, but quicker method? 
Be so kind as to prompt me.

Answer (score 0):

Your grid will have a [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore) under the hood of it. You can attach listeners to the store's [`datachanged`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-datachanged) and [`update`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-update) events:

```js
var handler = function() {
    // here you know that the grid has been edited
};
grid.mon(grid.getStore(), {
    //'update': handler,
    'datachanged': handler,
});
```

P.S. *"write data to the dick"*... you've made my day LOL

Comment: Thanks, 
in my program (ExtJS 4.x) 'datachanged' can't work but 'update' yes. 
 I use cell edit plugin in my grid panel with some control inside it. When I checked this handler after I set value of one cell extjs call this handler 39 times. Hm..  
P.S. Shame on me, but it’s single letter – and good information is that somebody have a LOL day

Comment: You can use the [`buffer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-on) option to catch only 1 time out of those 39.

Comment: By the way, can I ask you one more question concerning this horrible :-) ExtJS grid?

Comment: You are free to post another question here on StackOverflow. I am free to see if I can and want to answer :)

Comment: yes, thanks and sorry but I prefere to talk with the person rather then www (even if it's StackOverflow). Thank you for link to "on" definition, it;s clear.

Comment: One more info, please. I found that I can use listeners in the store definition and here 'update' give me the same possibility - inform me about grid (store) modification. OK, but here is the same difficulty with 39 calls. How can I solve this?

Comment: That's hard to tell without seeing the code, preferably in a fiddle, but, again, if those 39 calls happen around the same time they can be squashed into 1 by using the `buffer` option. This is not directly related to the original question though. If you want me to provide assistance you can contact me privately to discuss terms.

Comment: But I wanted to say that your suggested "buffer" solution is working. But only in case I use grid.mon(...as you prompted above.<br/> But I don't know how to use such a solution when I use listener with 'update' event in store definition. Only in this case I have this "magic 39".